# Snowflake task call stored procedure with parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can snowflake tasks call stored procedures with parameters for instance the date?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Snowflake tasks can call a stored procedure with a parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc( var1 varchar )
returns string not null
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
return 'var1=' + VAR1;
$$
;


CALL testproc( current_date );

create task test_task
WAREHOUSE = gokhan_wh
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
as
CALL testproc( current_date );

alter task test_task resume;

select * from table(information_Schema.TASK_HISTORY( task_name => 'TEST_TASK'));
```